# iCloud sync taking a long time

Tags: ios, icloud

I inserted in records on one iOS device and expected that record to be synchronized on another iOS device via iCloud, namely through `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` event.  Last week, I noticed the synchronization occurred pretty quick (roughly within 5 minutes).  Within the last few days, changes aren't synchronized until 12hours or more.  Has anyone encounter problem?

Comment: i suggest using parse... I have had the same issue with iCloud.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this problem made it impossible to test the app and take the risk of releasing the app without first testing (ughhh)

Comment: Yeah, i wish i cloud was better - parse now has a local data store, I'm still don't understand it but i see it taking over iCloud and core data.. unless apple step up their game.